# Undefined reference to cv::Feature2D::compute

Tags: opencv, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running **ROS Hydro** and **OpenCV 2.4.7**, using **openFabMap** and **SURF**. When I do catkin_make on my project, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `cv::Feature2D::compute(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat&) const'
```

I noticed that this happens when I write the following line of code:

```
cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
extractor.compute( cv_ptr->image, keypoints, descriptors_img);
```

**UPDATE**
Other cv classes, such as the **cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector** class work normally. It even instantiates the **cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor** with no problem. If I comment the "extractor.compute" call, I get no error.

I am including the following on the header:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

**UPDATE**
And my (complete this time) CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(compvision)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  image_transport
  cv_bridge
  sensor_msgs
  message_generation
)
find_package(OpenCV 2.4.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

 add_message_files(
    FILES 
    Match.msg
 )

 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES compvision
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
include_directories(
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(openFABMAPros src/fabmapTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(openFABMAPros ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(openFABMAPros ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(openFABMAPros ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_executable(image_converter src/image_converter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(image_converter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(image_converter ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(image_converter ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

Am I missing some dependencies? I don't recall this error happening when building with earlier versions of OpenCV.

Thanks for your time and support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109926/undefined-reference-to-cv::feature2d::compute/) by [Marcus Lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/9841/marcus-lopes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/9841/marcus-lopes/) on 2013-12-16**:
Installing ROS on another machine and running the same code there worked just fine ... well, I still don't know what might have happened, but that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Presumably there is more in your CMakeLists, in particular you have a line like:

```
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
```

What you are probably missing is:

```
target_link_libraries(foo ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                          ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

to actually link against the OpenCV libraries.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/9841/marcus-lopes/) on 2013-12-13**:
Thanks for the fast reply, fergs. So, I was fighting with the editor, but I managed to upload the whole CMakeLists file. It turns out I had the OpenCV_LIBS included there. I tried it with the syntax you used, but I got the same problem.

**Comment by [tarunuday](https://answers.ros.org/users/30296/tarunuday/) on 2018-07-07**:
I suggest you try out what's said [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/19083/how-do-i-install-opencv-to-work-with-ros/):

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foo ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                          ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```